# How to code for a mulitgroup analysis concerning two catagorical variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, multilevel-analysis, group-differences, growth-model

I have a question on syntax for Mplus.
I am running a multivariate latent growth curve with 7 repeated measures, variables X and Y (diagram attached). I also have two grouping variables, sex and country.
I asked the Mplus support how would I go about if I wanted Mplus to calculate the effects of X on Y depending on both sex and country,
(eg. the effect of X on Y given a male in country C and separate results for a female in country D)
Mplus support told me to run a multiple groups analysis but I cannot find any resources
that take two grouping variables in consideration. (conditioning on both sex and country)
Can anyone point me to some examples or resources that deal with a model like this?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option could be to combine the two grouping variables (sex, country) into a single grouping variable, for example, as follows:

Category 1: US males

Category 2: US females

Category 3: Canadian males

Category 4: Canadian females

Category 5: German males

Category 6: German females

and so on. Then run the multigroup analysis with the single combined grouping variable.

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried this after I posted the question. The result was an error (nonpositive-definite matrix). May be I should compare two at a time instead of four all together.

Comment: One reason for this maybe if your group sizes/group sample sizes are small. This could lead to Heywood cases (improper solutions, e.g., negative error variance estimates). More constrained models with measurement invariance (MI) across groups (equal loadings & intercepts) may not show this issue because they include fewer free parameters (although it should be tested whether MI is reasonable to assume).

Comment: That was what I thought, too. Since running the multigroup would split the sample into smaller sizes and because the model is pretty complex.